# Repository Spec file

Tags: rpm

I have source of webfiles. I need to make a RPM for it. I have placed my source in SOURCES folder and use following spec file. But it is creating noarch rpm with 2MB size, but my source is greater than 2MB size. Its also did not attach files with this. I think i have a problem in spec file.

```
Summary: my_project rpm script package
Name: my_project
Version: 1
Release: 1
Source0: my_project-1.tar.gz
License: GPL
Group: MyJunk
BuildArch: noarch
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-buildroot
%description
Make some relevant package description here
%prep
%setup -q
%build
%install
install -m 0755 -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/my_project
%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
%post
echo " "
echo "This will display after rpm installs the package!"
%files
%dir /opt/my_project
```

Comment: Need more info: What do you expect prep, build and install to do? Is this a binary you want to repack into an rpm? What are "webfiles"?

Answer (score 1):

try removoing the %dir tag in the %files section.  I.e.

```
%files
/opt/my_project
```